# How can I send an image from kafka producer in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, serialization, apache-kafka

I'm sending a numpy matrix from a kafka producer and it works perfectly:

```py
async def kafka_send(kafka_producer, data, topic):
    test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    x_enc = msgpack.packb(test, default=m.encode)
    encoded = base64.encodebytes(x_enc)
    await kafka_producer.send(topic, encoded)
```

On the other hand, if I try to send this code from a converted image to numpy, it does not send anything:

```py
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(post_data))
    arr = np.asarray(image)
```

Does anyone have this?

Comment: Question: Why do you need base64 on top of msgpack? You're just making the Kafka messages larger... And not clear how the second code is used... what is `post_data`?

Comment: @cricket_007 base64 was a test ... and post_data is the image sent by post in binary. I want to convert the received image in post_data to numpy to transform it and introduce it in a CNN using kafka python

Comment: So if `post_data` is already bytes, then you can just forward that to Kafka as-is... If the problem is with `np.asarray`, then this doesn't seem to be a Kafka issue... Note that Kafka does not immediately send messages, plus you have an await... You need to call `producer.flush()` after sending to have Kafka get anything. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/55538034/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 Nothing. I have tried but it still does not get the numpy matrix of the image, instead, any matrix created manually if it works ...

Comment: Another question: How large is that image or byte array? Kafka has a 1MB payload limit by default.

Comment: @cricket_007 Solving. That was the problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: There should have been a producer or broker error saying as much... If you would like to show how you solved the issue, feel free to post the answer below