# Python Producer can send via shell, but not .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a running and tested Kafka cluster, and am trying to use a Python script to send messages to the brokers. This works when I use the Python3 shell and call the producer method, however when I put these same commands into a python file and execute it - the script seems to hang.

I am using the kafka-python library for the consumer and producer. When I use the Python3 shell I can see the messages appear in the topic using Kafka GUI tool 2.0.4
I've tried various loops and statements in the python code, but nothing seems to make it 'run' to completion.

```
>>>from kafka import KafkaProducer
>>>producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='BOOTSTRAP_SRV:9092')
>>>producer.send('MyTopic', b'Has this worked?')
>>>>>><kafka.producer.future.FutureRecordMetadata object at 0x7f7af9ece048>
```

And this works and bytes appears in the broker topic data.

When I put the same code as above in a python .py file and execute with Python3 it completes, but no data is sent to Kafka broker.
No error shown either.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='BOOTSTRAP_SRV:9092')
producer.send('MyTopic', b'Some Data to Check')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see, it returns a future.

Kafka clients will batch records, they don't immeadiately send one record at a time, and to make it do that, you will need to wait or flush the producer buffer so that it'll send before the app exits. In other words, the interactive terminal keeps the producer data in-memory, running in the background, and the other way discards that data

[As the docs, show](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html#kafkaproducer)

```
future = producer.send(...)

try:
    record_metadata = future.get(timeout=10)
except KafkaError:
    # Decide what to do if produce request failed...
    log.exception()
    pass
```

Or just put `producer.flush()`, if you don't care about the metadata or grabbing the future.