# Using Python, how to produce kafka message more than 1MB?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, producer-consumer, producer

I was trying to transfer some huge json data through kafka, but its not happening.
Neither no error from python producer nor any messages on the consumer side.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="kafka_server")
product_message = json.dumps(data)
producer.send(kafka_topic, key=bytes('kk', 'utf-8'), value=bytes(product_message, 'utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the topic configuration [`max.message.bytes`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_max.message.bytes) to be able to produce the message.

Also, you can probably get a hint of what is going on by getting the future that send returns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55538034/19059974